# Drop missing values with dropna()

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to print out the first 10 rows with missing value but the output just print out all the data rows.
I'm also trying to drop all the missing value ('-') by using df.dropna() and setting na_values=['-'] but the output return an array with those rows with no missing value instead of the output.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("1.xlsx",index_col='Variables',na_values=['-'])
print("First 10 rows")
mydf = df.iloc[:, 0:10]
print(mydf)
print("Remaining dataset after dropping columns with missing data")
mydf1 = mydf.dropna()
print(mydf1)
```

Comment: You are selecting all rows and 10 columns

Comment: how to set condition? i have tried iloc but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

IIUC filter rows with at least one missing values and for first 10 rows use [`DataFrame.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html):

```
out = df[df.isna().any(axis=1)].head(10)
```